# Display instructions or other text in Plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, plugin, best-practices

I would like to display some basic text, instructions and maybe a change log in HTML would be nice, under the first tab of my Plugin, what methods or techniques are available?

In my sample screen shot below you can see a crude attempt I have tried using a field with a `type="textarea"` and the `default="some html and stuff"` but it is very limited.

[image]

I have looked at RegularLab's plugins and they appear to define fields with a placeholder or tag that I suspect gets replaced with its own information before it is displayed, which is what I would like to do however the RL approach seems to be require a lot of infrastructure behind it which is overkill for my plugins.

I vaguely recall seeing a more static approach to achieve the result I am after but I can't  remember where.

I haven't found anything in searching around so I am looking for some pointers on how to create it or even suggestions for other Plugins or Modules that display more than the basic fields that I can go and look at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note field can be used for this. HTML is supported.

```
<field
    name="instructions"
    type="note"
    label="PLG_SYSTEM_MULTIACCOUNT_FIELD_INSTRUCTIONS_LABEL"
    description="PLG_SYSTEM_MULTIACCOUNT_FIELD_INSTRUCTIONS_DESCRIPTION"
    filter="unset"
/>
```

Resulting output:

[image]